# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GeometricObject' - JetBrains pycharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error when i try to use Geometric module in pycharm IDE

```
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GeometricObject'
```

I have installed the module to the interpreter - Geometric but did not find GeometricObject

```
from GeometricObject import GeometricObject
import math

class Triangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side1=1.0, side2=1.0, side3=1.0, *args):
        super().__init__(*args);
        self.__side1 = side1
        self.__side2 = side2
        self.__side3 = side3
```

Comment: You say you want to import from the `Geometric` module but your code is `from GeometricObject import GeometricObject` instead of `from Geometric import GeometricObject`. What is the name of the module you're trying to import from?

Comment: I am learning Python and my textbook shows below code. I dont see a module GeometricObject in the Python Interpreter. In short; how do I get the GeometricObject module please?
from GeometricObject import GeometricObject

Comment: Have you installed the module you're trying to use? You might be trying to import a module you don't have...

Comment: I have been searching for the module from 1 hour - could not find anywhere... Tried in PyCharm interpreter but could not find it.... any thoughts?

Comment: It's not installed. Try installing the module

Comment: Hi Joel - the question is how to install this module? I dont see the module in the PyCharm project interpreter

Comment: Call `pip install GeometricObject` from the command line. This is the default way of installing any module that isn't built-in.

Comment: got the below error
C:\Users\usrysf\Desktop\CS521\venv\Scripts>pip install GeometricObject
Collecting GeometricObject
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GeometricObject (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for GeometricObject

Comment: In that case, the name of the module is not `GeometricObject`, which is your problem. Before installing the module, please take the time to research it and find its name. If you find it, there will likely be documentation online that will show you how to install and use the module.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will ask my professor. The text book shows the name of the module as GeometricObject